# react storybook - creating a composite component with context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context, storybook

I'm trying to access methods within a react context to create different variations of a composite storybook component and getting the error:

`React Hook "useEffect" is called in function "withItem" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function`. This is my setup:

I've got a react function component that uses context:

AppContext:

```
import React from 'react';
export default React.createContext();
```

MyComponent

```
import AppContext from '../../contexts/AppContext';

function MyComponent() {
  const { myItems } = useContext(
    AppContext
  );
```

and my `App.js` file uses a custom hook:

```
import useAppContext, { providerPropTypes } from './hooks/useAppContext';
```

where `useAppContext` contains various utilities and functions:

```
...
export default function useAppContext() {
  const onAddItem = product => {...}
  return {
    addItem: onAddItem,
    ...
  }

}
```

So in the attempt to populate a configuration of the storybook component where the component has added an item, I'm trying to do this:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { addDecorator } from '@storybook/react';

import useAppContext, { providerPropTypes } from '../../hooks/useAppContext';
import AppContext from '../../contexts/AppContext';

import MyComponent from './index';

import myItems from '../../mocks/myItems';

export default {
  title: 'Cart',
  decorators: [(storyFn) => {
    const appContextValue = useAppContext();

    return (
      <AppContext.Provider value={appContextValue}>
        {storyFn(appContextValue)}
      </AppContext.Provider>
    )
  }],
};

export const empty = () => {
  return (
    <MyComponent/>
  )
};

export const withItem = (appContextValue) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    appContextValue.addItem(myItems[0]);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Cart/>
  )
};
```

which is when I get the aforementioned eslint error.

How do I avoid this error (I notice that it is rendering properly behind the error message despite the eslint error)? What is the proper way to utilize context in composite storybook components?

Comment: hey, do you solve this? Cause I face this as well

Comment: Also curious if you got an answer to this? Having the same issue now as well

Comment: The question is not in createContext use. Error means that you need to move useEffect hook to React component. Now it is in arrow function and wont work.